# What is the rationale for not having duplicates across sites?

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange, duplicate-questions, cross-posting

I tried to flag a question on one SE site as a duplicate of another one on another SE site. It failed with the explanation that the duplicate must be within the same SE site.

What is the rationale for such limitation?

Comment: Mainly because each site has its own scope, community and culture.  You don't close Christmas as a duplicate of Hanukkah.

Comment: Honestly I expect that the reasoning is largely technical, rather than conceptual.

Comment: Certainly, but "do directory ACLs protect files underneath" is a fit for unix, security, rpi, debian, etc. and the answer will be exactly the same.

Comment: @servy: From a technical standpoint, SO is on its own database.  Even migrations are a bit problematic.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Wait, they are? How so? I haven't ever had any problems migrating things to SO (it's the same as migrating to any other site).

Comment: @Doorknob: From programmers, it's not uncommon for a migration to take 40 minutes to go through.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's not a *dupe*, it's a *cross-post*.

Scope varies wildly between sites: if you managed to make a question that's on-topic on Stack Overflow, Programmers and Code Review (I don't see how that could happen, but hypothetically speaking), the answers you would receive on each site would be tainted by the site's scope and purpose.

Stack Overflow would focus on fixing a specific issue; Programmers would address high-level design (don't quote me on that), and Code Review would explain how to refactor the code so that it's more efficient, while pointing out bad naming and other things that get pointed out in a peer review.

But somehow I think the real reason has more to do with the architecture of Stack Exchange sites, where a "duplicate" is apparently confined to a single database.

Comment: I think it is only a cross-post when a near identical question is placed on two or more sites by the same user.

Comment: @PolyGeo aah yes, that's correct.

Comment: I liked the sarcasm-tagged version of your answer better :)